# PHP mail() : multiple emails to single recipient or single email to multiple recipient

Tags: php, performance, email

I need to send one email to many recipients retrieved from a DB using mail() in PHP.

I was wondering if there is a performance or other differences between

1) Looping through all the recipients and calling mail() for each of them

2) Building a BCC header with all the recipients and calling mail() only once

Thank you !

Comment: The `mail()` function, is like the `<font>` tag it may work, but don't use it. Consider a mailing library like PHPmailer, it has features built in to send to multiple addresses, logging and you don't need to worry about header injections.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Ok, I will take a look. But nonetheless, in this scenario, would you recommand sending many emails to each recipient or 1 email to multiple recipients ? And why ?

Comment: If the emails are the same, id use a loop around the `$mail->addBCC();` method in batches of 10 on a cron job. Your thinking of doing it in the background right?

Comment: Yes, cron job. Still not clear to me what are the technical pros and cons of doing, say, 100 emails with 1 recipient vs 10 emails with 10 BCCs vs 1 email with 100 BCCs ?

Comment: Id put forward the difference being the connections/handshake overhead to the SMTP server, 100 vs 1, though with PHPmailer you can log/test it ;p.